# Read all the values in a node in xml with key value pairand print them in seperate line in

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file with key/value pairs.

XML file which I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MAN_J6_Variant>
    <play_music_media_HK>
        <key name ="Media_Press" value="echo 'Media::1' >> /pps/can/test_pps"/>
        <key name ="Media_Release" value="echo 'Media::0' >> /pps/can/test_pps"/>
        <key name ="Media_Source" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=258 -Y=26 -display=4 -relTimeout=0.5 " />
        <key name ="USB" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=480 -Y=134 -display=4 -relTimeout=0.5 " />
    </play_music_media_HK>
    <softkeys>  
        <key name ="Media_SK" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
  </softkeys>
    <play_music_media_SK>
        <key name ="bottom_home" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=755 -Y=455 -display=4 -relTimeout=0.5 " />
        <key name ="HS3" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=464 -Y=27 -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="Media_Source" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=258 -Y=26 -display=4 -relTimeout=0.5 " />
        <key name ="USB" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X=480 -Y=134 -display=4 -relTimeout=0.5 " />
    </play_music_media_SK>
    <Inside_media>
        <key name ="Media_Source" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="Browse" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="Audio_playing" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
    </Inside_media>
    <Inside_Media_source>
        <key name ="USB" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="SD1" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="SD2" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="USB1" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="IPOD" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
    </Inside_Media_source>
    <Inside_Media_Browse>
        <key name ="Artist" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
        <key name ="Albums" value ="./fs/etfs/Touch_new -X= -Y = -display= -relTimeout= " />
    </Inside_Media_Browse>
 </MAN_J6_Variant>
```

I need to print all the values in node `play_music_media_SK` in seperate line.

I wrote the below code in *linq*:

```
 var play_music_media_SK = doc.Descendants("play_music_media_SK").Select(x => new { play_music_media_SK = x.Attribute("name").Value, name = x.Attribute("value").ToString() });


//TestSetup.LogFile.WriteMsg("values in softkey"+taps);

  foreach (var value in play_music_media_SK)
  {
    console.writeline(value);
  }
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you correct results:-

```
var result = doc.Root.Element("play_music_media_SK")
                      .Elements("key").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("value"));

  foreach (var item in result)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
```

**Approach:** From the root node search for `play_music_media_SK` element, inside that look for `key` elements (using `Elements` since all are direct child of `play_music_media_SK`) then finally project the attribute `value`.